# Calling a void function on a c++ class

Tags: c++

I have a function on a class in C++ that is supposed to modify the member variables in an object in that class.  The function is required to have this signature:

```
void normalize()
{ 
    int& a = numerator;
    int& b = denominator;
    int modifier = Euclid(a, b); //euclidean algorithm
    if (modifier < 0) { modifier = modifier * -1; }
    a = a / modifier;
    b = b / modifier;
}

Rational temp(16, 84);
Rational temp2 = temp.normalize();
```

When called like this I am told that there is no constructor that can convert from void to Rational.

The function itself worked when implemented not as a "void."

I need to call this function on other objects, how do I do that when it cannot take an input, or yield an output? I.e. object.normalize() yields an error.

Edit: A solution was found, I just needed to implement it as `object.normalize()` without trying to do any assignment.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what problem you're having. `void` functions are pretty common for performing side effects. Why do you say it doesn't work when it's `void`?

Comment: "I.e. object.normalize() yields an error." What error? Why is this information missing from your question?

Comment: When `object.normalize()` “yields an error”, what is the error message, what is the type of `object`, and what class is `normalize()` a member of? **Show some code.**

Comment: I need to be able to call the function to modify the member variables in a class that "represents rational numbers" (i.e. has a numerator and denominator represented by integers) and I need to call the function on an object of that type. The error I receive is "no suitable constructor exists to convert from void to rational"

Comment: it sounds like you might be trying to assign the result of normalize to another variable of type rational. Could you show us the calling code?

Comment: "no suitable constructor exists to convert from void to rational" there is no code in your question that would generate such an error message.

Comment: Remove the `Rational temp2 = ` part.

Comment: I did try removing the "Rational temp2 = " part and that seemed to fix the issue. I have no idea what that might have changed but it solves the problem.

Comment: That is the correct solution. When you mutate variables in place, you don't return a new object; you simply keep using the original one.

Answer (score 1):

If the return type of a function is `void` the function **doesn't return anything**. So it makes little sense to have

```
Rational temp2 = temp.normalize();
```

With `void` functions, simply put them on a command of their own, without assignment.

```
// ...

temp.normalize();

// ...
```

Although if your intention **was** to have the function return something, consider changing the return type of the function to something suitable

```
Rational normalize()
{ 
    int modifier = Euclid(numerator, denominator);
    // ...
    numerator /= modifier
    // ...

    return ...;
}
```

Also note that *if* you can directly modify `numerator` and `denominator`, you don't need create references `a` and `b`.

Comment: Mhm. And whats the point of function local references to int?

Comment: OP might want to modify `numerator` and `denominator` without doing it explicitly. Is there a hindrance to using local references? I would like to know, I'm also learning. :3

Comment: @JohnLow There is just no point in doing so.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct foo {

    int bar;

    void normalize()
    {
        bar = 42; // modifies member ("by reference" makes no sense)
    }
};

// ...

foo object;
object.normalize(); // changes object
```

Comment: Perhaps explain why `Rational temp2 = temp.normalize();` causes an error?

Comment: because `temp.normalize();` doesn't return a damed thing. It alters `temp`.

Comment: If you want to keep the original `Rational` you'd have to `Rational temp; Rational temp42 = temp; temp.normalize();`.

Comment: @JohnLaw Sorry, in my answer `// changes output` was of course meant to say `// changes object`